# $_POST checking variables and files

Tags: php

I have the following few lines:

```
if ( (empty($_FILES["userFile1"]) ) or ( empty($_FILES["userFile2"]) ) or ( empty($_FILES["userFile2"]) ) ) {
    header("Location: " . "/");
}

// required fields
$required = array("userName", "userAddress", "userEmail");

// Loop over field names, make sure each one exists and is not empty
$error = false;
foreach ($required as $field) {
  if (empty($_POST["$field"])) {
    $error = true;
  }
}

// if error occurs
if ($error === true) {
    header("Location: " . "/");
}
```

But even if the user does not upload all three files, or even if the user leaves a field blank, the script still continues (I can tell by the side effects later in the script). Since the only thing that these do is redirect the user, obviously neither checks pass.

But if the fields are empty or files are not uploaded, why don't the checks work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exit maybe?

```
header("Location: " . "/");
exit;
```

An HTTP redirect is sent to the browser but the PHP script continues to execute.  You always need an exit after a redirect.

Comment: Probably also worth pointing out there's no need to concatenate the strings - `header("Location: /");` will work just fine and is marginally faster.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if ( (!isset($_FILES["userFile1"]) ) or ( !isset($_FILES["userFile2"]) ) or ( !isset($_FILES["userFile2"]) ) ) {
    header("Location: " . "/");
    exit;
}

// required fields
$required = array("userName", "userAddress", "userEmail");

// Loop over field names, make sure each one exists and is not empty
$error = false;
foreach ($required as $field) {
  if (!isset($_POST["$field"])) {
    $error = true;
    break;
  }
}

// if error occurs
if ($error === true) {
    header("Location: " . "/");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that! The script continues because no other data is sent to the client; the rest of the stuff that happens is on the server! So it sends the header and then just keeps going! Thank you.

Comment: @ jetawe sorry 7 mins to go